# how to pass data from one component to other component without using events

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

Iam parctising Flex these days. I just had 2 queries:

a) Can anyone tell me how to pass data from one component to other component without using events? I knew using events we can send data..

b) Iam thinking to do mobile applications uisng Flex, can u tell me where to start?

Comment: a) If you know what object will be your recipient, why don't you design its interface to accept devised dataset? And b) start by learning touch events, as they replace mouse events in mobiles.

Comment: @Vesper could U pls provide me an example for my query a) and is there any other suggestions for my query b)

Comment: Does this blog post help with the first question? http://www.flextras.com/blog/index.cfm/2013/2/1/How-does-one-Flex-Component-talk-to-another-Flex-Component

Comment: For a, you should build your application using the correct Flex patterns (which are, almost, the same as Java). Using MVC-like design, you would be able to let components communicate without events. In AS3/Flex, you can use something called views and helpers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a) Create Singleton class. You can share data between classes.
Like this

CustomSingleton.as

```
package modules.custom
{

public class CustomSingleton
{

    private var _g_data1: String;
    private var _g_data2: String;
    private var _g_object1: Object;

    public function CustomSingleton(internally:SingletonInternal)
    {
        super();
        if(internally == null)
        {
            throw new Error("Must use getInstance() Method.");
        }
    }
    public static function getInstance():CustomSingleton
    {
        return SingletonInternal.instance;
    }

    public function set g_data1(value:String):void
    {
        _g_data1 = value;
    }

    public function get g_data1():String
    {
        return _g_data1;
    }

    public function set g_data2(value:String):void
    {
        _g_data2 = value;
    }

    public function get g_data2():String
    {
        return _g_data2;
    }

    public function set g_object1(value:Object):void
    {
        _g_object1 = value;
    }

    public function get g_object1():Object
    {
        return _g_object1;
    }

}
}
import modules.custom.CustomSingleton;



class SingletonInternal{
public static var instance:CustomSingleton
    = new CustomSingleton(new SingletonInternal());
public function SingletonInternal(){}
}
```

Component1.as

```
public class Component1
{
     private var singleton: CustomSingleton = CustomSingleton.getInstance();
     public function hoge(): void
     {
          singleton.g_data1 = "aaa";
     }
}
```

Component2.as

```
public class Component2
{
     private var singleton: CustomSingleton = CustomSingleton.getInstance();
     public function hoge(): void
     {
          trace(singleton.g_data1);
          singleton.g_data1 = "bbb";
     }
}
```

b)Create Hello world app.
http://blog.air4android.com/2011/07/10/hello-world-air-for-android/

Answer (score 0):

To question a, you can use callback or observer instead of event

**callback**

Assume we have Component A and B, and the instances are a and b. Use callback  will make it no context needed.

```
b.callback = a.handler;

b.doSth();


// component define
Class A {

   public function handler(param:*):void {//you can have your param here

   }

}

class B {


   private var _callback:Function;//here you can use a array to save multi callbacks.

   public function set callback(value:Function):void {
       _callback = value;
   }

   public function doSth():void {
       //do something

       if (_callback  != null）　{
           _callback.apply(null, [some data]);
       }
   }
}
```

**Observer**

Here is some introduce to Observer, it looks like callback in some way.

[Observer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern)